# How to find the mass of this plate?

Tags: integration

I am having problems with this question, a plate described by $1 ≤ x^2 +y^2 ≤ 9$ has mass density given by $δ(x,y) = ex^2+y^2$. What is the total mass of the plate?

I tried doing $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 re^{r^2} dr d\theta$, but I end with the value $\pi(e^9-1)$, whereas the correct answer should be $\frac{1}{8}(e^9 - e)$. Can anyone explain what I did wrong and how should the question be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Double-check your limits of integration; you have $1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 9$. What should $r$ range from in your integral then?

Comment: How do you remove $\pi$ from the answer though?

Comment: You can't; as written, the mass is $\pi (e^9-e)$. @user208865, are you sure you gave us the right $\delta$/solution?

Answer (score 1):

The total mass has the formula: $M = \displaystyle \int_{A} \rho(x,y) dA$, the region $A$ is the annulus given by $1 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 9$, and $\rho = e^{x^2+y^2}$. Using polar coordinates:

$M = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{1}^3 e^{r^2}rdrd\theta=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{2}\left(e^9-e\right)d\theta=\pi(e^9-e)$